# validating through web service and saving password for application

Tags: java, save, md5, sharedpreferences, persistent

I am developing java application which consumes with the web service, which then validates the user,  I have the user enter his username and password. For using this application user required a valid username and password.

I have one context menu which will get activated when there is correct login. Otherwise i want it to get disabled.

And I want only a one time validation. So that, if any other user use that application from same system he dont need to enter the password again.

that means i need to save the password in local system, to use this password throughout the application

Any help regarding saving the password anyhow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use a public and private key to encrypt or decrypt password.

**Edit:**

First of all you have to create a public/private key pair. You need the tool openssl for this (http://www.openssl.org/source/ or directly for Windows http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html). 
Install it, open "cmd" (if you are on windows), navigate to your openssl installation path and enter following lines to generate the keys for server and client:

```
openssl genrsa -out serverPrivateKey.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in serverPrivateKey.pem -pubout -outform DER -out serverPublicKey.der

openssl genrsa -out clientPrivateKey.pem 2048
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in clientPrivateKey.pem -outform der -out clientPrivateKey.der
openssl rsa -in clientPrivateKey.pem -pubout -outform PEM -out clientPublicKey.pem
```

Now in your web service java application you can import the public key for **encryption**:

```
File pubKeyFile = new File("keys/serverPublicKey.der");
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) pubKeyFile.length()];

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pubKeyFile));
in.readFully(buffer);
in.close();

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(buffer));
```

and encrypt your password:

```
String text = password;

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
```

and save it to your local file system:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/encrypted");
fos.write(encrypted);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The other way for **decryption**.

Import the private key:

```
File privKeyFile = new File("keys/clientPrivateKey.der");
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) privKeyFile.length()];

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(privKeyFile));
in.readFully(buffer);
in.close();

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(buffer));
```

read the encrypted file:

```
File cryptedData = new File("/tmp/encrypted");
buffer = new byte[(int) cryptedData.length()];

in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(cryptedData));
in.readFully(buffer);
in.close();
```

and decrypt it:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(buffer);

String data = new String(decrypted);

System.out.println(data);
```

You just have to keep your private key secret on the system where your web service is running.
You can provide a web service function which provides the public key to the clients for encryption. Your clients just send the encrypted text string to the web service which decrypts it and authenticate your clients.

Comment: can u give me any example code for that...please

and my first preference is to save it in system so that it wont ask user again and again

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt. But in my code I can't take help from any third party software.

I am making a plugin for some software in java, and i need something like "Remember me" option on my ActionListener.
But in that case whenever a user clicks on button it automatically goes to some file, and next time automatically gets it from there.

Comment: This is no third party software. This is pure Java implementation.

Comment: No no, I mean the Openssl toolkit. I have to install it in every system I am going to use my software in.

Comment: No, that is not necessary. You only need OpenSSL to generate a public/private key pair once. I did not try it but on my own but it seems that you can also create a key pair online...but you should prefer command line tool!

Comment: Thanx alot, but this is the encryption and decryption of password.

I want the user to have the ability to enter the credentials only once and not be prompted again.

I need to persist the username and password for each device in local system where they can be retrieved when an web service call needs to be made.

Comment: Just check if the encrypted file does exist and pass it to the webservice in any case. You need only the login window one time to create the encrypted file. After that you can simply pass every time this encrypted file without showing login window again.